# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must either set a text or a view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to android and I keep getting this error while clicking on a button which process database requests.
I don't know what's going on because everything was working yesterday and I didn't do any changes at all.

The errorlog:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7510
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must either set a text or a view
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at android.widget.Toast.show(Toast.java:188)
    at com.example.myapplication.LoginActivity$userLogin$stringRequest$3.onErrorResponse(LoginActivity.kt:106)
    at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:617)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:104)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

And the code errorlog refers to:

```
private fun userLogin() {
        val email: String = emailText.text.toString().trim()
        val password: String = passwordText.text.toString().trim()

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
                Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    try {
                        val obj = JSONObject(response)
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                                    ?.userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("email"))
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("email", email)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }
```

Code which is calling this function:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
        userLogin()
        this.finish()
    }
}
```

Honestly, I have no idea what this error means, if I need to provide more code please let me know.

Comment: can you please share the code where you are calling this function?

Comment: check line number 173 of Preconditions.java

Comment: @ChiragRayani I edited the post with the code you asked

Comment: Sebastian :: Kindly log an error and check what message you are getting by volley. `Log.d("volleyError", "${volleyError.message}")`

Comment: @MuhammadAwais to be honest I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `Log.d("volleyError", "${volleyError.message}")` add this below `Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

Comment: I didn't change anything and it suddenly works. I have no idea what's going on

Comment: its related to android 11 version. keep version checker for now for temporary fix

Comment: it's causes because message string is `null` and in android 11 that's the cause

Answer (score 10):

in android 11(API level 30) `Compatibility.isChangeEnabled(CHANGE_TEXT_TOASTS_IN_THE_SYSTEM)` will return true in `Toast` class `show()` method, for android 11 as mention in [android developer site](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/compat-framework-changes#change_text_toasts_in_the_system)

for now if you want to skip this exception don't pass `null` in message parameter of Toast  `Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`
here your `obj.getString("message")` getting null for certain cases so you check null then show `Toast` like following

```
if(obj!=null && obj.getString("message")!=null){
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}else//static message
```

like this we can prevent exception

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun userLogin() {
        val email: String = emailText.text.toString().trim()
        val password: String = passwordText.text.toString().trim()

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
                Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    try {
                        val obj = JSONObject(response)
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                                    ?.userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("email"))
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        }
                           this.finish()
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("email", email)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
        userLogin()
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `userLogin()` method to this:

```
private fun userLogin() {
val email: String = emailText.text.toString().trim()
val password: String = passwordText.text.toString().trim()

val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
        Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                            ?.userLogin(
                                    obj.getInt("id"),
                                    obj.getString("email"))
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { volleyError->
            run {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d("volleyError", "${volleyError.message}")
            }
        }) {

    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("email", email)
        params.put("password", password)
        return params
    }
}
VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)

}
```

And everything seems to work, I have no idea why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must check for Toast message from before to be closed

```
    Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    // cancel previous toast and display correct answer toast
    try {
        if (mToast.getView().isShown()) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }
        // cancel same toast only on Android P and above, to avoid IllegalStateException on addView
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28 && mToast.getView().isShown()) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }
        mToast.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mToast.show();//This line will show toast if previous toast is null
    }
```

You this function in a global class , And use it for Toasting in anywhere